# simpleCursorAdapter without ListActivity?

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

would you please give me some tips that  how to use simpleCursorAdapter without ListActivity?
I mean ,I want to develop an application which use simpleCursorAdapter without listActivity,
frankly ,  If i dont use ListActivity, how I should set simpleCursorAdapter Items,
for example

---

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,cursor,from,**to**); or maybe

---

or maybe

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,.R.layout.mypage,cursor,from,**to**);

---

my problem is "**to**" Item,because I don't have any TextView in this page (XML file) ,I have tree field that I want to display in listView which I define in my XML file as "mylist",

Answer (score 0):

In your activity

```
private String [] project = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

...

    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                        project, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    startManagingCursor(phones);
    ContactCursorAdapter adapter = new ContactCursorAdapter(this, phones);
    ListView contactLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactLV);
    contactLV.setAdapter(adapter);
...
```

Your own Cursor Adapter class

```
 public class ContactCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        public ContactCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            TextView nameTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
            nameTV.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            TextView phoneTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phoneTV);
            phoneTV.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_for_lv, parent, false);
            bindView(v, context, cursor);
            return v;
        }


}
```

XML for ListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phoneTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer , but would you please explain it, i didnt get it, where should i define Textview? in which XML file,In my XML file is no TextView,It just include ListView and some buttons .

Comment: TextViews you must define in contact_for_lv.xml file. There are views that would be item (line) of your ListView.